# Prohibit direct access to images URL

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a blog with images. I do not want that the images are directly accessible through the URL (and also not for Googlebot and other bots)... for example... mysite.com/assets/images/img1... etc. So I thought to password protect the images directory with .htaccess. That worked, only front-end all my images became links, and I had to provide my credentials to make them show. How can I make my images show yet NOT make them directly accessible when typing the corresponding URL and the images URLs (or better yet the images directory) NOT accesible for bots to crawl/index?

Comment: You can restrict access to logged in users, but if you want them accessible to the general public, then there is nothing you can do to stop bots. refer checks etc just defeat poorly designed bots

Comment: This looks more like a question for ServerFault. However I've provided an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Don't go with password protection. The right way to do it would be to filter the requests based on the referer URL. If the request originates from your own site then it's ok. Otherwise the request is trying to get an image directly.

I've found this site with detailed instructions on how to do that: http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html

Taken from the mentioned site:

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(.+\.)?mysite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteRule .*\.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ http://url_to_default_image.gif [L]
```

Note that you would have to enable `mod_rewrite` in your Apache server.

Btw, just asking. Why don't just let people get the image directly if they want to?

Comment: just keep in mind that once a browser displays the image, the user can save it to wherever he wants. And it is fairly simple for a bot to fake the referer header

Comment: totally, like @steve said. That's why I asked if it wouldn't be better not to bother :|

Comment: HTTP_REFERER is unreliable, but that may be ok for you